# How to connect selenium webdriver to already existing instance of firefox browser

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

- In my code i am initially starting firefox browser via command prompt.
- I want to connect the firefox webdriver to this already open instance of firefox browser and not open new firefox browser.
  How do i implement this in selenium python.

Note:I am able to implement this for other browsers like chrome,edge but i dont find any way of doing it for firefox.

I also refered https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1669 ,but over here i am not sure how this --connect-existing works, it didnt work out for me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Repeating the answers in github: there is a flag

`--connect-existing`

to connect the geckodriver with existing firefox instance.
https://helpmanual.io/help/geckodriver/

Comment: This isn't working for me. It just opens two windows. Plus the tutorial you listed has nothing to do with --connect-existing.